Idea fails to load a maven untracable dependency
We are using internal Nexus for all maven dependencies, a direct access is prohibited. Suddenly, the maven import in IntelliJ Idea 2024.1 started to fail while maven command line is still working. Missing dependencies contains vulnerabilities and their binary jars were deleted from Nexus. I tried to locate where these libraries are coming from but they are not referenced in any of our projects and even maven transitive dependencies report cannot find them.
I turned on Maven to debug in Idea and I see the following:
[DEBUG]             com.auth0:jwks-rsa:jar:0.9.0:runtime
[DEBUG]                commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:runtime
[DEBUG]                commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:runtime
[DEBUG]                com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0.pr3:runtime
[DEBUG]                com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.1-jre:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[DEBUG]       org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[DEBUG]       org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[DEBUG]          org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[DEBUG]          org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[DEBUG]       org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[DEBUG]    org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.8.0:test
[DEBUG]       net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.14:test
[DEBUG]       net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.14:test
[DEBUG]       org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[WARNING] Failed to download camel-core-2.19.4.jar [https://nexus/nexus/content/groups/xx/]
[WARNING] Failed to download jackson-databind-2.10.0.pr3.jar [https://nexus/nexus/content/groups/xx/]
[WARNING] Failed to download camel-core-2.19.4.jar [https://nexus/nexus/content/groups/xx/]
[WARNING] Failed to download jackson-databind-2.10.0.pr3.jar [https://nexus/nexus/content/groups/xx/]

The following command runs successfully:
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install -DskipTests

I tried the following commands to locate these jars but they are missing in the output:
mvn dependency:tree > deps.txt
mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true > deps-effective.txt
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins > dep-resolved.txt 

I cleared all Idea caches and restarted. I removed .m2/repository too. I am stuck. What else can I try to find where they are coming from?
Updates
It looks like Maven does not care much about runtime dependencies, while IntelliJ idea breaks apart. We have identified where they are coming from in Idea maven debug logs and excluded them.

Yes, I can reproduce the error on a fresh clone.

That was the first thing I tried. The issue is resolved, see the update section in my post.
